# logrotate + how to control the secure logs under /var/log

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, logrotate

secure logs under /var/log in our server are more then 1G as the following

```
du -sh * | grep sec
0       secure
4.2G    secure-20210726
1.8G    secure-20210801
1.2G    secure-20210804
```

so we decided to rotate the secure logs once maxsize reached 100M

so we add the following to  /etc/logrotate.conf

```
more /etc/logrotate.conf
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.


/var/log/secure {
    monthly
        minsize 1M
        maxsize 100M
    rotate 5
}
```

then we removed the line `/var/log/secure` from `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` , in order to avoid duplicates entries

finally we refresh the log rotate as

```
logrotate  /etc/logrotate.conf
```

after some time we checked the logs secure under /var/log as

```
du -sh * | grep sec
0       secure
4.2G    secure-20210726
1.8G    secure-20210801
1.2G    secure-20210804
```

but as we can see above nothing was changed

so what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with your configuration. `logrotate` applies the rotation criteria to the current log file, it doesn’t check the attributes of rotated files (`secure-20210726` etc.).

You’ll only see changes in the rotated files once you have enough files to reach the rotation limit, at which point the oldest file will be deleted. You could enable compression, and manually compress the existing files.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at the timestamp, even before your change, the last successful rotation of the file was August 4, 2021, which is roughly today plus or minus the timezones we're in, so… what are you expecting to see already? logrotate is usually started once per day via cron job or systemd timer, so nothing will happen before that.

Calling `logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` manually will have done approximately nothing. Since logrotate isn't a daemon, you don't need to explicitly "reload the configuration", and it probably found that since logrotate often runs at night, the logfiles weren't old enough to rotate.

From your config, you'll see rotation in about a month, unless `secure` grows to more than 100M. (I'm spelling that out because personally, I rarely find the size options useful — I prefer regular rotation, even if it leads to small old log files, and if something happens that makes my logfiles explode, logrotate isn't going to save me anyway, so I'd just change the rule to `daily` and figure out how many days I want to keep.)